# How do I make the text color responsive on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to designing websites and bootstrap . Here goes my first question-
I have created a website using bootstrap. I want a particular text to change it's color from white to black to make it legible  when viewed on a mobile phone . Is there anyway I can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can make use of the concept of [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) for the same.

Change the width for mobile screen in the below code.

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```